# Error intellij IDE : External file changes sync may be slow

Tags: intellij-idea

I have this error in my IDE intellij

> IntelliJ IDEA cannot receive filesystem event notifications for the
> project. Is it on a network drive?

I can not continuous my developpement. Do you have idea?

Comment: What OS do you use? What's the location of the project? Is it a local disk? What file system is used?

Comment: I using Window 10 with wsl2 environnement and my project is on wsl repository.
\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\sodiki\Application

Comment: But before \\wsl$\ i see network and intellij installed on windows

Comment: What's your IntelliJ IDEA version?

Comment: My version intellij is IDEA 2022.2

Comment: WSL notifications are supported, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240351. If it doesn't work for you, please submit a new bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach the logs using Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.